# Determining if a pair exists in a large sorted array

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, interview-questions, complexity

I'm doing practice interview questions from [here](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Indeed-Software-Engineer-Interview-Questions-EI_IE100561.0,6_KO7,24_IP3.htm). Here is the one I am currently on - if you are given a very large sorted `int` array, then check of there exists a pair.

```
public static int sumOfTwoExists(int[] largeArray, int a, int b) {
    A: for(int count = 0; count < largeArray.length; count ++) {
        for(int counter = count + 1; counter < largeArray.length; counter ++) {
            if(largeArray[count] + largeArray[counter] == a + b) {
                return 1;
            } else if(largeArray[count] + largeArray[counter] > a + b) {
                break A;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I tested this code and it works. What I am having trouble with is the next part of the question - he asked if there's an optimal method \$O(1)\$ to find the match for the previous question?

How would you optimize this code so that the match is a constant time operation? I still don't how that would be done because it looks like iteration is still required.

Comment: `O(1)` is not possible. Let's assume that the first element is `0`. Then the problem turns into: check if  given number is present in a sorted array. It has an `O(log n)` lower bound.

Comment: `O(1)` is possible if you can use `O(n^2)` space to store the precomputed sums in a hash table.

Answer (score 5):

\$O(1)\$ is impossible indeed. Your solution is \$O(n^2)\$, because you ignore the most important part of the question: the array is *sorted*.

The \$O(n)\$ solution is to set a pair of iterators to the beginning and the end of the array. Then if a sum of their values is less than target, advance the beginning; if it greater, retreat the end. Keep going until they meet (or a target is found).

Answer (score 3):

Your question and your method signature indicate that you are confused.  The real question is, does there exist a pair of entries in the array whose sum is a particular target?

The input is an array and a target sum.

Since the answer is yes or no, the return type should be `boolean`.

```
public static boolean sumOfTwoExists(int[] array, int sum) {
    …
}
```

Comment: Yeah I should have used that intuition of two outputs - boolean. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the sums twice if the first condition isn't true, which is going to be the most likely case. Consider using variables for the sums and only doing the computation once:

```
public static int sumOfTwoExists(int[] largeArray, int a, int b) {
    A: for(int count = 0; count < largeArray.length; count ++) {
        for(int counter = count + 1; counter < largeArray.length; counter ++) {
            int sumArray = largeArray[count] + largeArray[counter];
            int sumInputNums = a + b;
            if(sumArray == sumInputNums) {
                return 1;
            } else if(sumArray > sumInputNums) {
                break A;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Also consider renaming your iterator variables to something more meaningful than `count` and `counter`. Even `i` and `j` would make it easier to distinguish between inner and outer loop. Using `count` and `counter` is error-prone and harder to debug.